# EJS with Express - i cant pass data from router to View but i still i get ReferenceError msg

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, router, ejs

Everything work fine till i want to display my form errors to user , i tried to pass errors from router to my view file?

**Error Msg**

```
ReferenceError: e:\2016\passport\views\register.ejs:38
   36|
   37|         <div class="alert alert-danger">
>> 38|         <% if (errors) { %>
   39|         <h2><%= errors %></h2>
   40|         <% } %>
   41|          </div>

errors is not defined
   at eval (eval at <anonymous> (e:\2016\passport\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:491:12), <anonymous>:11:12)
   at returnedFn (e:\2016\passport\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:520:17)
   at View.exports.renderFile [as engine]
```

**router.js**

```
router.post('/register',function(req,resp){
    var msg;
    var name= req.body.name;
    var username= req.body.username;
    var email= req.body.email;
    var password= req.body.password;
    var password2= req.body.password2;
    console.log('name   ' + password + "    email" + email);

        // validation using express validator
    req.checkBody("name"," the name filed should be there").notEmpty();
    req.checkBody("username","username is required").notEmpty();
    req.checkBody("email","email is required").isEmail().notEmpty();
    req.checkBody("password","password is required").notEmpty();
    req.checkBody("password2","passwords is NOT match ").equals(password);
        // collect all errors  there
    var errors=req.validationErrors();


    //Check the errors
    if(!errors && errors.length <=0){
        console.log(' No errors  errors ::  ' +errors.length  );
              }
    // if there is errors display them to users
    else{
       console.log("errors: "+ errors.length + JSON.stringify(errors));
            // now you pass data from router to view
        resp.render('register',{errors:errors});
    }

    });
```

**register.ejs**

```
<pre>
        <div>
        <P>Register</P>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <% if (errors) { %>
        <h2><%= errors %></h2>
        <% } %>
         </div>
</pre>
```

Everything work fine till i want to display my form errors to user , i tried to pass errors from router to my view file?

Comment: Your console.log is returning the array properly?

Comment: @nikjohn yes 


errors: 5 [{"param":"name","msg":" the name filed should be there","value":""},{"param":"username","msg":"username is required","value":""},{"param":"email","msg":"email is required","value":""},{"param":"email","msg":"email is required","value":""},{"param":"password","msg":"password is required","value":""}]

Comment: Could you try if(errors.length)? Though it shouldn't technically matter

Comment: Console.log(errors.length) will work file , but when you render the view it will show the the same error mentioned in this question " ReferenceError "

Comment: That's really odd. That _should_ work, at least from a Jade/Pug perspective, it should

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is this line right there: `!errors && errors.length <=0`. You're checking whether the errors-object is not set AND it has a length of 0 or less. So even if there are no errors, it will skip this check and hand an empty variable to the view, which results in the error you describe. Use `if (!errors)` instead.

Comment: I use if (!errors) but i still get the same error "ReferenceError"

Comment: Where have you tried (!errors)? You should put it in the JavaScript, not the ejs file. For the ejs file, try if (typeof errors !== "undefined")